# Laravel count unread messages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 5 tables:

**managers (id, name)** - store managers

**dialogs (id)** - store dialogs

**messages (id, dialog_id, text)** - store messages in dialogs

**dialog_manager (dialog_id, manager_id)** - store managers linked to this dialog

**messages_read (message_id, manager_id, read_at)** - store info when each manager reads each message.

My Dialog class have a relation:

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

Also Manager class have a relation:

```
public function dialogs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dialog::class);
}
```

Now i want to get number of unread messages for each dialog for selected manager like this:

```
$manager->dialogs()->withCount(['unread_messages']);
```

i've written the function for this:

```
public function unread_messages() {
   $managerId = 1285; // For example
   return $this->messages()->leftJoin('messages_read', function ($join) use ($managerId) {
        $join->on('messages.id', '=', 'message_id')->on('messages_read.manager_id', '=', DB::raw($managerId));
   })->whereNull('messages_read.read_at');
}
```

But it d't works - looks like "left join" just ignored because:

```
dd($manager->dialogs()->withCount(['unread_messages'])->get());
```

gives the error:

```
message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'messages_read.read_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `dialogs`.*, (select count(*) from `messages` where `dialogs`.`id` = `messages`.`dialog_id` and `messages_read`.`read_at` is null) as `unread_messages_count`, `dialog_manager`.`manager_id` as `pivot_manager_id`, `dialog_manager`.`dialog_id` as `pivot_dialog_id` from `dialogs` inner join `dialog_manager` on `dialogs`.`id` = `dialog_manager`.`dialog_id` where `dialog_manager`.`manager_id` = 1285)
```

What is the best way to solve my problem?

UPD: Added info about managers table.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is everything a relation but `messages_read` isn't?

Comment: I think it's the "right way" to go. Dialog, Manager and Message are entities - i have models for them. dialog_manager - just pivot table to link dialogs and managers. messages_read - table to storing read-data. I d't want to make model from it. But, if u think it's the correct way to build app, i'll make ManagerRead model also.
P.S. Added info about "managers" table

Comment: Oh, okay. Should also work your way. Don't mind me.

Comment: Why do you need `DB::raw()` in `$join->on('messages.id', '=', 'message_id')->on('messages_read.manager_id', '=', DB::raw($managerId))`?

Comment: You call `$manager->dialogs()->withCount(['unread_messages']);` but `unread_messages` isn't a relationship. So this won't work. You probably have to do something like this: `dd($manager->dialogs()->unread_messages->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT('*'))->get());`

Answer (score 0):

dont use an id in a relationship (you are not in any context)

Easiest way to do this :

```
$manager = Manager::with(['dialogs' => function($query){
   $query->withCount('messages as unread_messages_count' => function($query){
            $query->whereNull('read_at');
        });
}])->find($id);

$unread_message = $manager->dialogs->sum('unread_messages');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But your example only uses messages table, not messages_read table. The problem is - i have to get data from messages_read table, not messages table.
Messages table have no "read_at" field at all

Comment: then juste create a relationship between your read and unread message and add a ->has('unreadMessages') to your query

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I've found this solution for the unread_messages function:

```
return $this->messages()->where(function($query) use ($managerId) {
     $query->where('manager_id', '!=', $managerId)->orWhereNull('manager_id');
})->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($managerId)
     {
         $query->select(DB::raw(1))
             ->from('messages_read')
             ->whereRaw('messages_read.message_id = messages.id')->where('manager_id', '=', DB::raw($managerId));
     });
```

Maybe it's not optimal, but it works. Maybe i'll rewrite it one day when i'll have more experience in laravel.